# How to Get distance and duration in Google maps direction api

Tags: android, arrays, json, google-maps, google-directions-api

I am trying to add distance and duration that we get from google maps  direction api. I don't much about JSON so please help me to add distance and direction in following code.

To distance and direction we have to use JsonObject like following code

```
JSONObject jsonLeg = jLegs.getJSONObject(0);
JSONObject jsonDistance = jsonLeg.getJSONObject("distance");
JSONObject jsonDuration = jsonLeg.getJSONObject("duration");
String distance = jsonDistance.getString("text");
String duration = jsonDuration.getString("text");
```

But I don't know where to add and how to add that code.

Following is my DirectionsJSONParser.java

```
package com.example.locationwaypointmapv2;

class DirectionsJSONParser {
List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> parse(JSONObject jObject){

    List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = new ArrayList<List<HashMap<String,String>>>();
    JSONArray jRoutes;
    JSONArray jLegs;
    JSONArray jSteps;

    try {

        jRoutes = jObject.getJSONArray("routes");

        for(int i=0;i<jRoutes.length();i++){
            jLegs = ( (JSONObject)jRoutes.get(i)).getJSONArray("legs");

            List<HashMap<String, String>> path = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            for(int j=0;j<jLegs.length();j++){
                jSteps = ( (JSONObject)jLegs.get(j)).getJSONArray("steps");

                for(int k=0;k<jSteps.length();k++){
                    String polyline;
                    polyline = (String)((JSONObject)((JSONObject)jSteps.get(k)).get("polyline")).get("points");
                    List<LatLng> list = decodePoly(polyline);

                    for(int l=0;l<list.size();l++){
                        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<>();
                        hm.put("lat", Double.toString((list.get(l)).latitude) );
                        hm.put("lng", Double.toString((list.get(l)).longitude) );
                        path.add(hm);
                    }
                }
                routes.add(path);
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return routes;
}

private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {

    List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<>();
    int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
    int lat = 0, lng = 0;

    while (index < len) {
        int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lat += dlat;

        shift = 0;
        result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lng += dlng;

        LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
                (((double) lng / 1E5)));
        poly.add(p);
    }

    return poly;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to get `Distance` and `Duration`

```
    final JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
 JSONArray routeArray = json.getJSONArray("routes");
 JSONObject routes = routeArray.getJSONObject(0);

 JSONArray legsArray = routes.getJSONArray("legs");
 JSONObject newDisTimeOb = legsArray.getJSONObject(0);

 JSONObject distOb = newDisTimeOb.getJSONObject("distance");
 JSONObject timeOb = newDisTimeOb.getJSONObject("duration");

 Log.i("Diatance :", distOb.getString("text"));
 Log.i("Time :", timeOb.getString("text"));
```

Here is a complete [Example](https://inducesmile.com/android/android-find-distance-and-duration-between-two-points-on-android-map/)